# Remove duplicates from pandas series based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas series as:

```
    increased   1.691759
    increased   1.601759
    reports     1.881759
    reports     1.491759
    president   1.386294
    president   1.791759
    exclusive   1.381759
    exclusive   1.291759
    bank        1.386294
    bank        1.791759
    ........    ........
    ........    .......
```

I just wants remove duplicates words from series and by retaining the word with a higher numeric value. So, expected output,

```
increased   1.691759
reports     1.881759
president   1.791759
exclusive   1.381759
bank        1.791759
........    ........
........    .......
```

I have tried it by converting a series into pandas dataframe an it works fine. But, it would be time consuming process as I have large series. So, all I want to process in existing series only.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `drop_duplicates` after you sort `col2`. Drop duplicates keeps the first by default, so if you sort by `col2` so that the largest is first, it will keep the largest:

```
df.sort_values('col2', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('col1')

        col1      col2
2    reports  1.881759
5  president  1.791759
9       bank  1.791759
0  increased  1.691759
6  exclusive  1.381759
```

**Alternative using `groupby` and `tail`**:

Another way would be to do this:

```
df.sort_values('col2').groupby('col1').tail(1)

        col1      col2
6  exclusive  1.381759
0  increased  1.691759
5  president  1.791759
9       bank  1.791759
2    reports  1.881759
```

**Edit**: Based on your comment, to convert to a series for further use you can do:

```
df.sort_values('col2', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('col1').set_index('col1')['col2']

col1
reports      1.881759
president    1.791759
bank         1.791759
increased    1.691759
exclusive    1.381759
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Or do a groupby directly on the series (but this is slower, see benchmarks):

```
s.sort_values().groupby(s.index).tail(1)
```

---

**Benchmark**

I tested this with a `Series` of length 1000000, and even with transforming it to a dataframe and back to a series, it takes less than a second. You might be able to find a faster way without transforming, but this isn't so bad IMO

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.choice(['increased', 'reports', 'president', 'exclusive', 'bank'], 1000000), 'col2':np.random.randn(1000000)})

s = pd.Series(df.set_index('col1').col2)

>>> s.head()
col1
president    0.600691
increased    1.752238
president   -1.409425
bank         0.349149
reports      0.596207
Name: col2, dtype: float64
>>> len(s)
1000000

import timeit

def test(s = s):
    return s.to_frame().reset_index().sort_values('col2', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('col1').set_index('col1')['col2']

>>> timeit.timeit(test, number=10) / 10
0.685569432300008
```

Applying `groupby` directly on a Series is slower:

```
def gb_test(s=s):
    return s.sort_values().groupby(s.index).tail(1)

>>> timeit.timeit(gb_test, number=10) / 10
0.7673859989999983
```

Comment: Using `last` and averting `ascending=False` . `df.sort_values('col2').drop_duplicates('col1', keep='last')` .

Comment: Thanks,but I want to remove duplicates in series. Your code works fine but I have to convert it again into series as I need a series for further use.

Comment: See my edits for a note on performance. There could possibly be faster ways, but I don't think this is so bad... Also, you can do the `groupby` directly on a series (see under **Edit**)

Comment: @sacul Thanks, it works. One more thing if any two words values are equal then  I want one of them. For example-  `president 0.988 president 0.988` 
 then I want one `president 0.988`

Comment: I believe the code I provided does that, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this method will work on Pandas Dataframe but you can try using `set()` function. The `set()` function removes all duplicates.

Comment: How would he ensure that the values removed are smaller than the ones kept

Comment: And converting a dataframe to a set is not efficient

Comment: `Set()` works fine in arrays but I'm not sure about pandas.series()

Comment: Like I said it might not be the best - sorry. I can remove my answer. Please let me know.